# Finding the last duplicate row in (Oracle) SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

We have a *history* table which is defined as follows:

```
--ID (pk) -----------Object ID--------------Work ID--------date------
  1                  1111                   AAAA           1/1/2010
  2                  1111                   AAAA           1/2/2010
  3                  2222                   BBBB           1/1/2010
  4                  3333                   CCCC           1/1/2010
  5                  1111                   DDDD           1/3/2010
```

We need the latest (date-based NOT id-based) row PER Work ID.  Note that an object ID can have multiple work id's and we need the latest for EACH work ID.

What we need as our result set:

```
ID (pk) -----------Object ID--------------Work ID--------date------
2                  1111                   AAAA           1/2/2010
3                  2222                   BBBB           1/1/2010
4                  3333                   CCCC           1/1/2010
5                  1111                   DDDD           1/3/2010
```

Thoughts/Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  h.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workID ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
        FROM    history
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table a where (a.date, a.work_id)  in (select max(b.date), b.work_id from your_table b where a.work_id=b.work_id group by work_id)
```